# Docker y una base de datos

Tags: mysql, python, django, docker, docker-compose

Estoy usando Docker para una aplicación web.

El tema es que localmente no tengo nada en mi base de datos pero sí tengo el .sql, con los datos de los usuarios registrados, etc.
¿Cómo podría insertar estos datos a mi proyecto local?

Antes utilizábamos virtualenv, y lo pasamos a Docker.

Comment: No sé en qué BBDD trabaja esa app .pero si es una MySQL podrías usar la consola de MySQL para insertar ese archivo sql

Comment: Si tienes el schema de tu DB creada en tu workstation local, puedes usar herramientas como por ejemplo: [dbeaver.io](http://dbeaver.io) para realizar la migracion. En mi caso trabajaba en una DB Windows SQL 2008 realizaba una copia de mi schema, despues una copia de mis datos; en mi local machine de pruebas, montaba otro SQL server re-creaba el schema (.sql) y despues insertaba la copia de los datos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!